# Training a NN on top of cached embeddings from a pre-trained model, loss not going down?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I have some embeddings, which are the output of a pre-trained model, saved to disk. I am trying to perform a binary classification task of accept/reject. I have trained a simple  neural network to perform classification, however, I am not seeing any decrease in the loss after some time.

Here is my NN, the cached embeddings are of shape 512:

```
from transformers.modeling_outputs import SequenceClassifierOutput
class ClassNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_labels=2):
        super(ClassNet, self).__init__()
        self.num_labels = num_labels
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(512, 256, bias=True),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Dropout(p=.5, inplace=False),
            nn.Linear(256, 128, bias=True),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Dropout(p=.5, inplace=False),
            nn.Linear(128, num_labels, bias=True)
        )
    def forward(self, inputs):
        
        return self.classifier(inputs)
```

This is some random architechture that I am trying to over-fit to, but it seems that the network plateau's quickly on the training data. Could it be that my data is too complicated?

here's my training loop:

```
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-4,weight_decay=5e-3) #  L2 regularization
loss_fct=nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

model.train()
for epoch in range(10):  # loop over the dataset multiple times
    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, data in enumerate(train_loader):
        # get the inputs; data is a list of [inputs, labels]
        inputs, labels = data['embeddings'], data['labels']

        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(inputs)
        logits = outputs.squeeze(1)
        loss = loss_fct(logits, labels.squeeze())
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        running_loss += loss.item()
        if i % 2000 == 1999:    # print every 2000 mini-batches
            print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' %
                  (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 2000))
            running_loss = 0.0
        

print('Finished Training')
```

The loss is stuck at around .4 and doesn't really decrease at all after an epoch.

To give a little context, the pre-trained embeddings are the output of specially trained ViT model from HuggingFace, I am trying to perform a classification task directly on the outputs of that model by building a simple neural network on top of it.

Can anyone advise on what is going wrong? Also if anyone has any suggestions to get a better accuracy, I would love to hear it.

Comment: How many epochs? How long is the training? What value does `num_labels` have?

Comment: I am doing this for 10 epochs, training takes around 15mins and num_labels is 2 (binary classifcation)

Comment: Did you plot the training loss function over iterations (or epochs)? Also are you computing a loss and/or metric on a validation set?